# COUNT function?

Tags: php, database, matching

How do i assigned the correct number of students to a position available
Eg...
TABLE NAME : JOB_DETAILS

```
COMPANY: ABC
NO_OF_VACANCY : 3
ASSIGNED : 3
jobscope : IT
```

query ran to match the number of students to fill up the number of students assigned is HALF correct :

```
UPDATE job_details,student_details SET assigned=no_of_vacancy WHERE student_details.jobscope = job_details.jobscope AND student_details.jobscope = 'IT';");
```

TABLE NAME : student_details

```
name : A1
Jobscope : IT 

name : A2
jobscope : IT

"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student_details WHERE jobscope1 ='IT';
```

The problem is i want to insert the CORRECT number of student name into another matching table in the database to show .

The company and student name beside

eg . Company ABC - A1 
     Company ABc - A3

How do i create a query to count the number of student who chose it and Update the job_details table to count the correct number of students to assign to the company abc.

The query1 is wrong as the results show vacancy 3 and assigned is 3. 
i want it to show vacancy 3 and assigned is 2 since the number of students who chose IT is only 2.